# Regex for Current NTUSER.DAT files

Tags: regex, pcre

I am trying to come up with a regex (PCRE) that finds current windows NTUSER.DAT files when cycling through a file list (valid NTUSER.DAT are the ones that are in the correct path for use by Windows).

I am trying to exclude any NTUSER.DAT files that have been copied by a user and placed in a different location (e.g. on the Desktop). In the following sample data, the first 4 results are valid, the next 3 are invalid:

```
\Users\John Thomas Hamilton\ntuser.dat
\Users\Default\NTUSER.DAT
\Users\Mary Thomas\NTUSER.DAT   
\Users\UpdatusUser\NTUSER.DAT
\Users\John Thomas Hamilton\Desktop\My Stuff\Windows\Users\Default\NTUSER.DAT
\Users\John Thomas Hamilton\Desktop\My Stuff\Windows\Users\Student\NTUSER.DAT
\Users\John Thomas Hamilton\Desktop\My Stuff\My stuff to sort\Tech Support Fix it\NTUSER.DAT
```

Currently the best/simplest regex I have is:

```
\\USERS\\[A-Z0-9]+\\NTUSER.DAT$
```

but of course there a plenty of valid Windows file name characters other than letters and numbers that could exist in the user name.

I think i need to search up to the first occurrence of the new folder "\" and then if it does not have NTUSER.DAT after it, reject it. I have not had any luck doing this so any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well assuming you have a valid file list, this would work:

```
^\\Users\\[^\\]+?\\NTUSER.DAT$
```

Make sure you ignore case.

The secret is using `[^\\]+?` instead of `.+?` so that you match exactly one folder length in.

Comment: Thank you. That works well. It's looks simple when you see it in front of you!